# Rotation of a vector field across the circle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

Please help me to solve the following problem:

Given a circle $C:$ $x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 4$ compute the rotation of the vector field $F(x,y) = \{1+x-2y+y^2, x^2- (1-y^2)^4 + y(y-2)(2y -1)\}$ across $C$.

My attempt:

I have a feeling that I somehow use should linearization. I also feel that the theorem stating that rotation of a vector filed is equal to sum of indexes of special points (points where the vector field is not defined or not continuous or equal to zero) may be useful. But I do not see how to apply these ideas.

Thanks a lot for your hints and answers!

Comment: rotation or rotational ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about correct term. Please advice. Mathematically it is the following: split closed curve into non-closed paths and compute the sum of rotations for each path. It does not depend on the choice of paths. Rotation along the path $ab $is $\frac{1}{2\pi}( \theta(b) - \theta(a))$ where $\theta$ is the angle of a vector field vector.